# Unable to establish connection between client and server in C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a program in C, were I have to use sockets.
If I use a generic IP (INADDR_ANY), client can successfully establish a connection to the server, but if I use another IP, like "192.168.1.100", the connection fails.

**Server->**

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), fd_sock, dim, dim1;
struct sockaddr_in my_addr, *client = (struct sockaddr_in*) malloc (sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.200");

bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
listen(sock, N*N);

while(1){
    fd_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)client, &dim1);
    dim = read(fd_sock, buf, 100);
    buf[dim] = '\0';
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, dim); 

    close(fd_sock);
}

close(sock);
```

**Client->**

```
int port = atoi(argv[2]) // I give the port as second argument from code line
char *ip = malloc(15); // I give IP as first argument from code line
strcpy(ip, argv[1]);
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), fd_sock;
struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.200");
connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
write(sock, ip, 15);
```

---

If instead of

```
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.200");
```

I use

```
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);
```

Both on client and server, the socket connection works just fine.

Any solutions?

Comment: Which ip-addresses are assigned to the server's interfaces?

Comment: OT: `dim1` should be declared `socklen_t`, not `int`.

Comment: You aren't really doing `... = inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);`, are you?

Comment: the ip assigned to server's interface is 192.168.1.100
but if i pass INADDR_ANY, i don't know what ip it is

Comment: ehhhm.. yes i'm doing. why? wich is the problem?

Comment: If the server carries `192.168.1.100` you won't be able to reach it under `192.168.1.200` (as per the code you show), that's for sure.

Comment: if i don't use INADDR_ANY, it doesn't work

Comment: and wich IP must i use?

Comment: Any address one of the server's interfaces exposes. Which as per your comment above would be `192.168.1.100`.

Comment: can you show me wich code will u use for client and wich for server?
i'm quite confused

Comment: Also, if your "real" code not already does, you do yourself a big favour, adding error checking to all (relevant) system call. As there are per the code shown those at least are `bind()`, `accept()`, `read()`, `write()` and `connect()`.

Comment: Change both `"200"` to be `"100"`. The client wants to connect to the address the server had bound itself to.

Comment: A nice guide to network programming is here: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ or if you want to go for all of it, you might like to read this book: http://unpbook.com

Comment: yes , i'm using .100 and i don't know why, but the client wait for a while for close itself.

Comment: i have Advanced Unix Programming, from stevens too.

Comment: Add the error checking as per my previous comment, then compile with debug symbols and run the code inside a debugger. Reading here gives you a picture on how to help yourself: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Can you ping `192.168.1.100` from the client machine's console?

Comment: ok, now i'll read.
i tried to display the output of the read from server, and the write from client, but i see nothing

Comment: Did you add the error checking as advised?

Comment: Then there is no need to wonder. Check out the network setup on both machines using `ipconfig` and  `route`.

Comment: ehmm nope, i'm on a single machine.
the program must work on 2 differents machines, and also on the same machine

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eskvgsfb2865l76/Schermata%20del%202015-05-16%2013-20-08.png?dl=0
this is the result of the ping

Comment: i tried the error cheking
into the client, the connect give me -1
but from read from server, i recive nothing.

Comment: If the phone company connects me, it gives me a number. This is the number which will make my phone ring. This is the same number I must give to other people if I wish to be contacted. Using this analogy, you've been given a number, then chosen to listen for calls to a different number (calls which the telephone exchange _wont_ deliver to your handset), while at the same time asking people to contact you on this same, fictitious number... The address of this machine on my local network is 192.168.43.84 - _this_ is the number I must pass to `inet_addr`, not something else of my choosing.

Comment: but i use the same ip on each program

Comment: now i tried use this code before start the connect/accept

           printf("IP address is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(my_addr.sin_addr));
 printf("port is: %d\n", (int) ntohs(my_addr.sin_port));

and each 2 programs show me the same ip and port.
but they not connect

Comment: If any of the system calls return you -1 then call `perror("<system call> failed")`.

Comment: 'Unable to connect' and 'the connection fails' are not problem descriptions. You should have called `perror()` in your *original* code,as @alk said, if *any* system call returned -1, and posted the error message here in your original question. Your entire question so far has been a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

**but if I use another IP, like "192.168.1.100"**

Are  you sure your private ip is 192.168.1.100? If not make sure it by using command ipconfig in windows or ifconfig in linux

Also it seems that both your client and server are on the same machine.
Have you tried the localhost ip(127.0.0.1)? This is an ip which always points to the same machine no matter which machine you are on.